# Include timepicker into table with bootstrap-4

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4, momentjs, datetimepicker

I'm trying to add a timlepicker into an html table with the JS librariries **bootstrap-4.min.js** and **moments-with-locales.min.js**.

For that I've an html table with an input for the timepicker, this is my project : https://jsfiddle.net/Geo_x/fv0oqdpx/12/

The problem is my time picker is not "on" my table it's "in" my table :

[image]

I tried `position:relative` and others options but it wasn't a great success.

Can you help me please ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `position:absolute` for this class `.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget`

```
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget{
  background-color:green;
  position:absolute;
}
```

check the updated [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Udhaytitus/9w6f57mx/)

Answer (score 0):

I made a code snippet of HTML only that doesn't need to incorporate the "position: absolute;" CSS property and makes your DateTimePicker much more readable - the one you had was green in the background with bullet points without any visible increment and decrement arrows. My snippet also includes a clickable calendar icon.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">       </script>  
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
<table class="contenu_popup">
  <col width=auto><col width=auto>
  <tr>
    <td id="test1">test line 1</td>
    <td><input type="text"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="test">TimePicker test</td>
    <td>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker3' style="margin-top:  5px">
          <input type='text' class="form-control"/>
          <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="test2">test line 3</td>
    <td><input type="text"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```